# Adding property to second level objects of multi-level array

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, tree, multi-level

Being stuck for the whole day trying to find out the clue.

I have a three levels tree array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "uuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижники",
        "slug": "spodvizhniki",
        "order": 1,
        "hasContent": false,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "uuid": "sabit-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Сабит ибн Кайс Аль-Ансари ",
                "slug": "sabit",
                "order": 1,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "uuid": "khabbab-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Хаббаб ибн аль-Аратт",
                "slug": "khabbab",
                "order": 2,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "uuid": "suraka-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Сурака ибн Малик",
                "slug": "suraka",
                "order": 3,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "uuid": "rabi-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "ар-Раби бин Зияд аль-Хариси",
                "slug": "rabi",
                "order": 4,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "uuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижницы",
        "slug": "spodvizhnicy",
        "order": 5,
        "hasContent": false,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "uuid": "asma-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Асма бинт Абу Бакр | «Обладательница двух поясов",
                "slug": "asma",
                "order": 2,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "uuid": "rabia-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Рабиа ибн кааб",
                "slug": "rabia",
                "order": 3,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "uuid": "safiya-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Сафийа бинт Абдуль Мутталиб",
                "slug": "safiya",
                "order": 4,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "uuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Жёны Пророка ﷺ",
                "slug": "zheny-proroka",
                "order": 5,
                "hasContent": false,
                "level": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "uuid": "khadidzha-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Хадиджа бинт Хувайлид",
                        "slug": "khadidzha",
                        "order": 1,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 24,
                        "uuid": "aisha-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Аиша бинт Абу Бакр",
                        "slug": "aisha",
                        "order": 2,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 25,
                        "uuid": "sauda-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Сауда бинт Зама",
                        "slug": "sauda",
                        "order": 3,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 26,
                        "uuid": "ramlya-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Рамля бинт Абу Суфьян",
                        "slug": "ramlya",
                        "order": 4,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 27,
                        "uuid": "hafsa-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Хафса бинт Умар",
                        "slug": "hafsa",
                        "order": 5,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I want to add the hasThirdLevel: true property to the 2nd level objects if the children array is not empty. Tried a lot but could't find the clue.

Also the tree array was created from flat array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "uuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижники",
        "slug": "spodvizhniki",
        "order": 1,
        "hasContent": false
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "uuid": "sabit-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "name": "Сабит ибн Кайс Аль-Ансари ",
        "slug": "sabit",
        "order": 1,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "uuid": "khadidzha-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
        "name": "Хадиджа бинт Хувайлид",
        "slug": "khadidzha",
        "order": 1,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "uuid": "asma-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "name": "Асма бинт Абу Бакр | «Обладательница двух поясов",
        "slug": "asma",
        "order": 2,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "uuid": "khabbab-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "name": "Хаббаб ибн аль-Аратт",
        "slug": "khabbab",
        "order": 2,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "uuid": "aisha-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
        "name": "Аиша бинт Абу Бакр",
        "slug": "aisha",
        "order": 2,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "uuid": "rabia-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "name": "Рабиа ибн кааб",
        "slug": "rabia",
        "order": 3,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "uuid": "suraka-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "name": "Сурака ибн Малик",
        "slug": "suraka",
        "order": 3,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "uuid": "sauda-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
        "name": "Сауда бинт Зама",
        "slug": "sauda",
        "order": 3,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "uuid": "rabi-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "name": "ар-Раби бин Зияд аль-Хариси",
        "slug": "rabi",
        "order": 4,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "uuid": "ramlya-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
        "name": "Рамля бинт Абу Суфьян",
        "slug": "ramlya",
        "order": 4,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "uuid": "safiya-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "name": "Сафийа бинт Абдуль Мутталиб",
        "slug": "safiya",
        "order": 4,
        "hasContent": true
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "uuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "name": "Жёны Пророка ﷺ",
        "slug": "zheny-proroka",
        "order": 5,
        "hasContent": false
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "uuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижницы",
        "slug": "spodvizhnicy",
        "order": 5,
        "hasContent": false
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "uuid": "hafsa-uuid",
        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
        "name": "Хафса бинт Умар",
        "slug": "hafsa",
        "order": 5,
        "hasContent": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right you want the object with id 22 to have additional property 'hasThirdLevel: true' because its children is not empty?

```
for(let mainItem of arr) {
    for(let secondItem of mainItem.children)
    {
        if(secondItem.children.length > 0)
        {
            secondItem["hasThirdLevel"]=true;
        }
    } }
```

Here is the code for that. If that's not it kindly paste the result you want in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Here's your tree array
const treeArray = [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "uuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижники",
        "slug": "spodvizhniki",
        "order": 1,
        "hasContent": false,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "uuid": "sabit-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Сабит ибн Кайс Аль-Ансари ",
                "slug": "sabit",
                "order": 1,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "uuid": "khabbab-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Хаббаб ибн аль-Аратт",
                "slug": "khabbab",
                "order": 2,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "uuid": "suraka-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Сурака ибн Малик",
                "slug": "suraka",
                "order": 3,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "uuid": "rabi-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "ар-Раби бин Зияд аль-Хариси",
                "slug": "rabi",
                "order": 4,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "uuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижницы",
        "slug": "spodvizhnicy",
        "order": 5,
        "hasContent": false,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "uuid": "asma-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Асма бинт Абу Бакр | «Обладательница двух поясов",
                "slug": "asma",
                "order": 2,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "uuid": "rabia-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Рабиа ибн кааб",
                "slug": "rabia",
                "order": 3,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "uuid": "safiya-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Сафийа бинт Абдуль Мутталиб",
                "slug": "safiya",
                "order": 4,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "uuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Жёны Пророка ﷺ",
                "slug": "zheny-proroka",
                "order": 5,
                "hasContent": false,
                "level": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "uuid": "khadidzha-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Хадиджа бинт Хувайлид",
                        "slug": "khadidzha",
                        "order": 1,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 24,
                        "uuid": "aisha-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Аиша бинт Абу Бакр",
                        "slug": "aisha",
                        "order": 2,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 25,
                        "uuid": "sauda-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Сауда бинт Зама",
                        "slug": "sauda",
                        "order": 3,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 26,
                        "uuid": "ramlya-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Рамля бинт Абу Суфьян",
                        "slug": "ramlya",
                        "order": 4,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 27,
                        "uuid": "hafsa-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Хафса бинт Умар",
                        "slug": "hafsa",
                        "order": 5,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// and here's a result which is the same as your tree array except the 
// second level items have the extra property that indicates if they
// have children

const result = treeArray.map(firstLevelItem => ({
  ...firstLevelItem,
  children: firstLevelItem.children.map(secondLevelItem=>({
    ...secondLevelItem,
    children: secondLevelItem.children,
    hasThirdLevel: !!secondLevelItem.children.length
  }))
}))

result
```

Here's the result:

```
[
  {
    id: 13,
    uuid: 'spodvizhniki-uuid',
    parentUuid: null,
    name: 'Сподвижники',
    slug: 'spodvizhniki',
    order: 1,
    hasContent: false,
    level: 1,
    children: [
      {
        id: 14,
        uuid: 'sabit-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhniki-uuid',
        name: 'Сабит ибн Кайс Аль-Ансари ',
        slug: 'sabit',
        order: 1,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      },
      {
        id: 15,
        uuid: 'khabbab-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhniki-uuid',
        name: 'Хаббаб ибн аль-Аратт',
        slug: 'khabbab',
        order: 2,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      },
      {
        id: 16,
        uuid: 'suraka-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhniki-uuid',
        name: 'Сурака ибн Малик',
        slug: 'suraka',
        order: 3,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      },
      {
        id: 17,
        uuid: 'rabi-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhniki-uuid',
        name: 'ар-Раби бин Зияд аль-Хариси',
        slug: 'rabi',
        order: 4,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    uuid: 'spodvizhnicy-uuid',
    parentUuid: null,
    name: 'Сподвижницы',
    slug: 'spodvizhnicy',
    order: 5,
    hasContent: false,
    level: 1,
    children: [
      {
        id: 19,
        uuid: 'asma-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhnicy-uuid',
        name: 'Асма бинт Абу Бакр | «Обладательница двух поясов',
        slug: 'asma',
        order: 2,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      },
      {
        id: 20,
        uuid: 'rabia-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhnicy-uuid',
        name: 'Рабиа ибн кааб',
        slug: 'rabia',
        order: 3,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      },
      {
        id: 21,
        uuid: 'safiya-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhnicy-uuid',
        name: 'Сафийа бинт Абдуль Мутталиб',
        slug: 'safiya',
        order: 4,
        hasContent: true,
        level: 1,
        children: [],
        hasThirdLevel: false
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        uuid: 'zheny-proroka-uuid',
        parentUuid: 'spodvizhnicy-uuid',
        name: 'Жёны Пророка ﷺ',
        slug: 'zheny-proroka',
        order: 5,
        hasContent: false,
        level: 1,
        children: [
          {
            id: 23,
            uuid: 'khadidzha-uuid',
            parentUuid: 'zheny-proroka-uuid',
            name: 'Хадиджа бинт Хувайлид',
            slug: 'khadidzha',
            order: 1,
            hasContent: true,
            level: 1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 24,
            uuid: 'aisha-uuid',
            parentUuid: 'zheny-proroka-uuid',
            name: 'Аиша бинт Абу Бакр',
            slug: 'aisha',
            order: 2,
            hasContent: true,
            level: 1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 25,
            uuid: 'sauda-uuid',
            parentUuid: 'zheny-proroka-uuid',
            name: 'Сауда бинт Зама',
            slug: 'sauda',
            order: 3,
            hasContent: true,
            level: 1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 26,
            uuid: 'ramlya-uuid',
            parentUuid: 'zheny-proroka-uuid',
            name: 'Рамля бинт Абу Суфьян',
            slug: 'ramlya',
            order: 4,
            hasContent: true,
            level: 1,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 27,
            uuid: 'hafsa-uuid',
            parentUuid: 'zheny-proroka-uuid',
            name: 'Хафса бинт Умар',
            slug: 'hafsa',
            order: 5,
            hasContent: true,
            level: 1,
            children: []
          }
        ],
        hasThirdLevel: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by iterating and checking the length of 3rd level children array length.

```
inputArray.forEach(obj => {
    obj.children.forEach(childrenObj => {
    childrenObj['hasThirdLevel'] = childrenObj.children.length ? true : false;
  })
});
```

Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "uuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижники",
        "slug": "spodvizhniki",
        "order": 1,
        "hasContent": false,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "uuid": "sabit-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Сабит ибн Кайс Аль-Ансари ",
                "slug": "sabit",
                "order": 1,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "uuid": "khabbab-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Хаббаб ибн аль-Аратт",
                "slug": "khabbab",
                "order": 2,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "uuid": "suraka-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "Сурака ибн Малик",
                "slug": "suraka",
                "order": 3,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "uuid": "rabi-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhniki-uuid",
                "name": "ар-Раби бин Зияд аль-Хариси",
                "slug": "rabi",
                "order": 4,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "uuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
        "parentUuid": null,
        "name": "Сподвижницы",
        "slug": "spodvizhnicy",
        "order": 5,
        "hasContent": false,
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "uuid": "asma-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Асма бинт Абу Бакр | «Обладательница двух поясов",
                "slug": "asma",
                "order": 2,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "uuid": "rabia-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Рабиа ибн кааб",
                "slug": "rabia",
                "order": 3,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "uuid": "safiya-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Сафийа бинт Абдуль Мутталиб",
                "slug": "safiya",
                "order": 4,
                "hasContent": true,
                "level": 1,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "uuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                "parentUuid": "spodvizhnicy-uuid",
                "name": "Жёны Пророка ﷺ",
                "slug": "zheny-proroka",
                "order": 5,
                "hasContent": false,
                "level": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "uuid": "khadidzha-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Хадиджа бинт Хувайлид",
                        "slug": "khadidzha",
                        "order": 1,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 24,
                        "uuid": "aisha-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Аиша бинт Абу Бакр",
                        "slug": "aisha",
                        "order": 2,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 25,
                        "uuid": "sauda-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Сауда бинт Зама",
                        "slug": "sauda",
                        "order": 3,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 26,
                        "uuid": "ramlya-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Рамля бинт Абу Суфьян",
                        "slug": "ramlya",
                        "order": 4,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 27,
                        "uuid": "hafsa-uuid",
                        "parentUuid": "zheny-proroka-uuid",
                        "name": "Хафса бинт Умар",
                        "slug": "hafsa",
                        "order": 5,
                        "hasContent": true,
                        "level": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

arr.forEach(obj => {
    obj.children.forEach(childrenObj => {
    childrenObj['hasThirdLevel'] = childrenObj.children.length ? true : false;
  })
});

console.log(arr);
```